# How to fix 'Unable to cast object of type Button to DataGridView' error in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I made multiple dynamic datagridviews that has the instance above. The dgv's are in my flowlayoutpanel and I also created an event of CellClick for every datagridview.

```
for (int = 0; i <= 5; i++){
     dgv = new DataGridView();
     dgv.Name = "dgv" + i;
     dgv.CellClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dgv_CellClick);
}
```

This is the event that I made for the dgv's

```
private void dgv_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){
     DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
     for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
          if (dgv.Name == ("dgv" + i.ToString())){
               dgv.Rows[0].Cells[0].BackColor = Color.Red;
          }
     }
}
```

As you can see, I used the object sender to follow up the dgv's that I created earlier. And now, I want to implement the event to make contact with the specific datagridview and change it's color using different controls. But when I used that, It crashes and errors InvalidCastException 'Unable to cast object of type 'control here' to type 'DataGridView'. Can someone help me?

Comment: No but that is not the case. I have 2 sets of datagridviews and when I click the first dgv, the second set must be also clicked in the first dgv.

Comment: When you get the exception, click on "Copy Details" and paste the details to your question.  That way we can help you locate the source of the error from the stack trace.

Comment: Does this always occur? Or only if you have a `Button` inside the cell you click on?

Comment: You should show how a Button ended up inside that Cell. A DGV ButtonColumn will set `sender` to the owner DGV, not a Button type.

Answer (score 1):

For a safe casting I suggest you to enclose your event handler code into a conditional check as shown below. It would at least allow you to put a break point and examine which control is raising the click handler so that you can do necessary changes.
Though this may not necessarily fix your issue but at least help you to debug without instantly crashing your application.

```
private void dgv_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     if(sender is DataGridView)
     {
        DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
          if (dgv.Name == ("dgv" + i.ToString())){
               dgv.Rows[0].Cells[0].BackColor = Color.Red;
          }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: This can be shortened to `if (sender is DataGridView dgv)`. You can then skip the `DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;`. This only works with C# 7+ though